# Synchronize concurrent batch updates with JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jpa, transactions

This example is modified and simplified, but resembles a real problem I have with legacy code that I am trying to fix.

I have a MSSQL `CAR` table (where `id` is the primary key)

| id | make | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW | WASHED |
| 2 | BMW | DIRTY |
| 3 | BMW | DIRTY |
| 4 | Ford | DIRTY |
| ... | ... | ... |

and a `/washNextCars` endpoint.

```
@PatchMapping("/washNextCars")
public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> washNextCars(
      @RequestBody WashCarBody body,
      @RequestParam String status,
      @RequestParam String make,
      @RequestParam Integer limit) {
  ...
}
```

The following request changes the state of the next `10` cars from `DIRTY` to `WASHED`

```
PATCH /washNextCars?status=DIRTY&make=BMW&limit=10
{
    "status": "WASHED"
}
```

This is the rough business logic:

```
  @Transactional
  public List<Car> washNextCars(WashCarDTO dto) {

    // SELECT TOP ? * FROM CAR WHERE make=? AND status='DIRTY' ORDER BY id ASC 
    List<Car> nextCars = carRepository.findNextCars(limit, make, status);

    // do some complex validation on every car if it can be washed, therefore can't do everything in one single UPDATE query

    cars.forEach(car -> {
      car.setStatus("WASHED");
    });
    carRepository.saveAll(nextCars);
  }
```

This endpoint works fine when called in sequence, but when called in parallel, it tries to perform the update to the same set of cars at the same time, not the next batch of cars.

**Questions:**

- How can I synchronize the calls until the first one is done?

  - Note this has to be achieved on the database level, because the API is deployed as multiple replicas
- I found the following options:

  - `@Transactional(isolation = READ_UNCOMMITED)`

    - This would require to update the cars to `WASHED` before any other statement in the business logic is executed, is that correct?
  - `@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE_LOCK)` - Did not provide the desired effect
- What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: What you can do it have some state that says "inProcess". When you fetch next 10 cars, you first update them to this flag in a transaction, and then fetch them. Then another process can't "steal" your cars. Important is that your endpoint / something releases these cars in case some error occurs, otherwise the cars will be stuck inProcess forever

Comment: Use of a status flag should require using optimistic locking so that if two concurrent processes take overlapping cars and both try mark them as inProgress, the second to commit will detect the overlap and fail. Your process needs to expect such an error and requiry to get the 'latest' X dirty cars and retry (or tell the caller to do so). What issue did you have with pessimistic locking? Locking upfront (select for update)  is certainly one way to prevent another process from getting the next set of cars while the transaction is in progress, but it slows things down to operating sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Try with UPDLOCK:

```
SELECT ... FROM tab1 WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE ...
```

Something similar to

> SELECT FOR UPDATE

in Oracle.